# How can I transform a google chart graph to an image and save her?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, xslt, google-visualization

First, sorry if my english isn't really good,

I have some google charts (using the API) and I want to transform them to images.

For do that, I use this code :

```
var chart_div = document.getElementById('chart_div');
var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(chart_div);

// Wait for the chart to finish drawing before calling the getImageURI() method.
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    chart_div.innerHTML = '<img src="' + chart.getImageURI() + '">';
    console.log(chart_div.innerHTML);
});

chart.draw(dataAge, optionsAge);
```

And the problem is that I have to place a div

```
<div id='chart_div'></div>
```

for seeing my image.

My question is how can I save that image on my server? Of course, after I had save her I want to use her for make a PDF document using a jsp file and a xsl and delete the image.

Answer (score 0):

write javascript method that you have to be called on click of a button (or on any event).Inside the javascript method use jquery get or post method and send the image data to server. Image data can be initialized to a global variable and later send using calling the method

Answer (score 0):

Recently i read all those questions about save google chart to image files on the disk but no one solution give me what i need.  So i started to try with a kind of programs that simulate web browser and the result is perfect what i need.
This is what solved the question to me:

1) create a page with all you need, your google chart running, using your server-side language or not to create the final code and all other stuff.

2) download phantomjs (freeware), this is the webbrowser emulator.

3) phantomjs use a script that tell what it will do, the perfect script for this case is:

save.js

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.viewportSize = { width: 360, height: 150 };
page.open('http://your-webserver.com/yourgooglechart.html', function() {
  page.render('image_to_save.png');
  phantom.exit();
});
```

- notice the viewportSize is the virtual size of your browser view.

4) run C:\blabla\phantomjs.exe save.js

worked like a charm

5) in my case, i schedule it to run every 5 minutes and consume this image in other place of my solution.

Answer (score -1):

This type of code has incomptibilidades with IE and Firefox, it works fine with Chrome and Opera.
I could not find a solution to this Code specifically, but I use another method, which was compatible with all browsers.
For this I think on the main page container with an image inside a DIV and the occult

```
<div style="display:none;">
<img id="chartImg" />
</div>
```

Position the image that is generated with the API at the URL:

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    var imgUri = chart.getImageURI();
    // do something with the image URI, like:
  document.getElementById('chartImg').src = imgUri;
});
```

Then through openWin function, I think a pop and write within this image, a graphic, which can be copied on the derecgo botonn mouse and save it as PNG.

```
function openWin() {  
   var divText = document.getElementById("chartImg").outerHTML;   
    var myWindow = window.open('', '', 'width=500,height=500');
   var doc = myWindow.document;
   doc.write('<img' + ' id="graficar" ' +' />');
   doc.write(divText);
   doc.write("<p>This is 'myWindow'</p>");
   doc.close();
}
```

In jsFiddle ahy an example to modify.

http://jsfiddle.net/rdmghzhm/7/